# How to combine str and int to return the date at end of the month?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file that has a Year column (int) and a Month column (str).

| Year | MonthLong |
| --- | --- |
| 1984 | January |
| 1984 | January |

I'd like to have the last day of each month in a separate column (dd/mm/yy).

I've tried lots of dumb things (just learning and still trying too many of my excel work arounds) but am at a loss now.

```
months = {'January':1, 'February':2, 'March':3, 'April':4, 'May':5, 'June':6, 'July':7, 'August':8, 'September':9, 'October':10, 'November':11, 'December':12}

#Creates a column with month as a number
tax_cols['Month'] = tax_cols['MonthLong'].map(months)

#Adds a day column to get to_datetime to work - day is wrong
tax_cols['Day'] = tax_cols['MonthLong'].map(months)

#Creates a full date column - day is wrong
tax_cols['FullDate'] = pd.to_datetime(tax_cols[['Year', 'Month', 'Day']])
```

From here I have tried datetime/relativedelta and monthrange with no success. Any ideas how I can move this forward?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `%Y%B` for specified year in `YYYY` and month in month name format and for lass day of month add [`offsets.MonthEnd`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd.html):

```
date = pd.to_datetime(tax_cols['Year'].astype(str) + tax_cols['MonthLong'], format='%Y%B')
tax_cols['FullDate'] = date + pd.offsets.MonthEnd()
print (tax_cols)
   Year MonthLong   FullDate
0  1984   January 1984-01-31
1  1984   January 1984-01-31
```

If possible some different format you can use `errors='coerce'` for `NaT` for this wrong datetimes:

```
date = pd.to_datetime(tax_cols['Year'].astype(str) + tax_cols['MonthLong'], format='%Y%B', errors='coerce')
tax_cols['FullDate'] = date + pd.offsets.MonthEnd()
print (tax_cols)
   Year MonthLong   FullDate
0  1984   January 1984-01-31
1  1984   January 1984-01-31
```

Comment: Hey Jezrael, this pulls up a ValueError: unconverted data remains:

Comment: Thanks Jezrael. Errors coerce looks like a handy feature! I must check the dataset for any NaN values now. Thank you.

Comment: Turns out the 'December   ' has white space after it!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to know last day of month. For example

```py
def last_day(month: int, year: int) -> int:
    last_days = {
        1: 31,
        2: 28,
        3: 31,
        4: 30,
        5: 31,
        6: 30,
        7: 31,
        8: 31,
        9: 30,
        10: 31,
        11: 30,
    }
    if month != 2 or (year % 4 != 0 or (year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 != 0)):
        # month is not Feb and year is common
        return last_days[month]
    return 29
```

Then you can use `datetime` module for formatting:

```
from datetime import date


def formatted_date(year, month) -> str:
    return date(year, month, last_day(month, year)).strftime("%d/%m/%y")


print(fotmatted_date(1985, 1))
# 31/01/85
print(formatted_date(1984, 2))
# 29/02/84
```